# Dates and Epochs in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

Dates will be the end of me. So, I'm trying to work with dates and converting them to and from epochs. But, before I even get to that, I need to understand what is going on with the number of ticks (and TotalSeconds).

If I compare the following 2 dates:

```
var dateUtc = new DateTime(2000, 6, 14, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var dateLocal = new DateTime(2000, 6, 14, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local);
```

They both have an identical number of ticks. My local timezone is +9.30 hours.
That being the case, those 2 dates are not the same instant in time. The 2nd date is 9.5 hours earlier than the first. So, why do they both have the same number of ticks? 630965376000000000

Extending this, lets look at the next 2 lines of code:

```
var epoch1 = (dateUtc - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalSeconds;
var epoch2 = (dateLocal - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalSeconds;
```

Both epoch1 and epoch2 are the same. Why?

There seems to be something about the C# implementation of DateTime that I am missing.

Comment: Have a look at `DateTimeOffset` it's efficiently `DateTime` in UTC + TimeZone (in the form of `TimeSpan`)

Comment: `DateTimeKind` is a *separate flag*. It doesn't affect the stored tick value. If you want a type with offsets use DateTimeOffset. Instead of guessing, you can simply [check the source file](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs)

Comment: If you care about offsets and epochs though you should probably switch to [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org/) Dates and times are a lot more complex than an epoch and offset. *Timezones* aren't the same thing as offsets and change all the time

Comment: BTW just search SO for `[c#] Persian Calendar`. *All* languages have serious issues with date and time handling, which is why libraries like JodaTime for Java and NodaTime for C# exist

Comment: Thanks guys. I was aware of NodaTime. I was aware of offsets and Timezones being different. But I did not realize that DateTimeKind does not affect the tick value. Seems like an enum I'll never ever have a use for. Will see how I go with DateTimeOffset and if not so well, will look to NodaTime.